# How to set the Decomposition Tree to show the most recent week as default in power bi

Tags: powerbi, tree, decomposition

I have a Decomposition Tree presenting the sales in four columns Year, Quarter, Month and week in power bi. I would like to set the tree to show the most recent week when i open the report.

Comment: No body knows ???